# Submit a form through select onchange and through button. Different values for an input

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

I have a form with different `<select>` fields and with a button. I want to submit the form when onchange a select and when clicking the button. But, I have another hidden input field and I want the value of this hidden field to be different if the form is submitted through onchange or through clicking the button.

Thank you very much.

```
<form method="get" action="stats2.php" id="myform">
<select name="year" id="selYear" onchange="this.form.submit()">
<option value=2015>2015/16</option> 
<option value=2014>2014/15</option> 
<option value=2013>2013/14</option>
</select> 
<input type="hidden" name="myinput" value="0"/></input> 
<input type = "submit" value="Run it!"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: Can i post some code you have been trying so that we can help you to get further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do add a javascript function to handle the onchange event;

```
<form method="get" action="stats2.php" id="myform">
    <select name="year" id="selYear" onchange="onChange()"> 
    <option value=2015 <?php if ($year==2015) { echo "selected='selected'";}?>>2015/16</option> 
    <option value=2014 <?php if ($year==2014) { echo "selected='selected'";}?>>2014/15</option> 
    <option value=2013 <?php if ($year==2013) { echo "selected='selected'";}?>>2013/14</option> 
   <input type="hidden" name="myinput" value="0"/> 
   <input type = "submit" value="Run it!" onclick="onSubmitClick()"/></form>
```

Your JavaScript you can create on change event handler for `selYear`

```
<script>
   function onChange(){
       document.getElementsByName("myinput")[0].value = "changed";
       document.getElementById("myform").submit();      
  }

  function onSubmitClick(){
       document.getElementsByName("myinput")[0].value = "Something else";
       return true;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Any possibility of changing the value not when onchange but when clicking the button?

Comment: @Javi Yes, you can add an onclick event handler to the html tag. I edited my post

Comment: Thanks. It works for the button but it does nothing when changing de select... Probably Im doing something wrong...

Comment: ok. It should be myform.submit() instead of this.form.submit() in the script. But, now, the value of myinput is "something else" even when not clicking...

Comment: @Javi, hmm, that is weird. May be you are calling onClick() somewhere else in your code? Anyway, change the function name to something else.

Comment: Actually, neither the onclick nor the onchange works. They don't change the value at all, or at least, the new value does not pass through url...

Comment: @Javi, you are welcome. If you think it works, please accept the answer. Thanks